# How to use FK SQL in a relation M:1

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf

i need to understand how to work with FK SQL,i'm really desperate. I've a FK between two tables. From a third table i select what item i want to Execute(those item's are local urls). I select them, i run them, i need to save in the third table(tabStoricoDetail) a code referred to the items started. STOP if i manage how to do that i can then try to pickup the first date of the first event and the last date of the last item. I thought that the FK that i've made was ok but it's not. PLEASE HELP PLEASE
[image]

```
//btnStart it allows to lunch the selected items 
private void btnSTART_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

  ApplyExecuteResults(ExecuteResults());//non toccare



  sqliteCon.Open();
  if (sqliteCon.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
  {


    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tabStoricoDetail(NomeItem,ResItemDet)values('Prova','RProva')", sqliteCon);
    /*cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATESD", this.DPStart.Text);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATEED", this.DPEnd.Text);*/
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd1.Parameters.Clear();


    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tabStoreExec SET FK_TSD_id =(tabStoricoDetail.id)", sqliteCon);
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd2.Parameters.Clear();


    MessageBox.Show("Dato Aggiunto");

  }
  sqliteCon.Close();


}
```

[image]

Comment: Which SQL engine are you using? Judging by your connection object name, it's sqlite, but can you confirm?

Comment: nope was a try but it didn't work for me but the name stayied there

Comment: i figured out two points 1.I'VE TO CREATE A RECORD IN TSD WITH A SPECIFIC id,WITH A NAME DEPANDANT FROM THE ITEMS SELECTED AND STARTED, WITH A GENERAL RESULT OF THE ITEM STARTED.

Comment: 2. I'VE TO UPDATE FK_TSD_id INSERTING  INTO THE INTERESTED ITEMS(WHEN tabList=1) AND WHICH HAS BEEN STARTED(FIGURED OUT THAT NOW) THE VALUE OF tabStoricoDetail.id

Comment: I'm asking what kind of database system you're using.

Comment: SQL pure nothing strange, wanna keep it easy

Comment: It's like you don't even want to be helped.... Which product? Is it SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, Postgres, sqlite, ...? Could you show the connection string?

Comment: I just don't wanted to be obvious but SQL MANAGEMENT STUDIO...SQL Server

Comment: How to use FK SQL in a relation M:1,i need to understand how to work with FK SQL, the image...

Comment: Sorry I couldn't see the image, imgur is blocked where I am. I'll answer in a minute.

Comment: thank you hope you'll see somehow the image because it's a screenshot of the db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When inserting a row into `tabStoricoDetail` you will need to save the generated ID into a variable. Note the `OUTPUT` clause of the `INSERT` statement:

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tabStoricoDetail(NomeItem,ResItemDet) OUTPUT inserted.Id VALUES ('Prova','RProva')", sqliteCon);
/*cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATESD", this.DPStart.Text);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATEED", this.DPEnd.Text);*/
int generatedId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd1.ExecuteScalar());
cmd1.Parameters.Clear();
```

Then you just use this `generatedId` when updating `tabStoreExec`, although you probably want some kind of `WHERE` on that `UPDATE`, because right now you'll just update all the existing rows.

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tabStoreExec SET FK_TSD_id = @tsdId", sqliteCon);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tsdId", generatedId);
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: ok you are near the solution, every FK_TSD_id now has obtained value 4 don't know why

Comment: are you able to understand the formation of that table? i've put it to show to you that insted of one row in TSD it builds 4 ROWS

Comment: i've inserted into the question another image to show it to you

Comment: Of course every FK_TSD_id is getting value 4 (or whatever ID of the last inserted row), your `UPDATE tabStoreExec` statement has no `WHERE` condition in it, so all rows in there will get updated. And it builds just one row, you've probably clicked that button in the past and inserted a number of rows into your database... 

Please spend some time learning about databases and programming in general, I'm sorry but it feels like you're lacking fundamental knowledge. It's not my job to "be near the solution", I and others can help you out but you need to show some effort.

Comment: sure,sorry i was only happy to be near the solution like never before, so i've only to put a where tabList.selction=1 condition in it and it's done

Comment: buut i've to connect somehow tabList to tabStoreExec without connecting them